# How can i pass following arguments in main through argc and argv?

Tags: qt

```
static void build_preprocess_command(int e_flag)
{
    ivlpp_main(argc, argv);
    snprintf(tmp, sizeof tmp, "%s%civlpp %s%s -F\"%s\" -f\"%s\" -p\"%s\" ",
           pbase, sep, verbose_flag?" -v":"",
           e_flag?"":" -L", defines_path, source_path,
           compiled_defines_path);
}
```

I want to pass the snprintf's argument in ivlpp_main() as argc or argv.

Comment: `ivlpp_main()` is declared as `int ivlpp_main(int argc, char**argv)` ?

Comment: yes ivlpp_main() is declared as int ivlpp_main(int argc, char** argv);

Answer (score 0):

In C `argc` is int and `argv` is a vector of arguments. If this is true here you can pass that string only in argv.

However, you should decide whether the entire string is a single argument or it contains multiple arguments for your main function. Please comment on this and I'll add the answer for that case.

Edit: Then you'll have to add each of them to the array. Try something similar to:

```
 static void build_preprocess_command_and_run(int e_flag)
 {
   char **argv;
   int argc, arg;

   argc = 7; /* you have 6 args maximum plus one NULL at the end */
   argv = calloc(argc, sizeof(argv[0]));
   arg = 0;

   snprintf(argv[arg++], strlen(pbase) + 2 + strlen("ivlpp"), "%s%ccivlpp", pbase, sep);

   if (verbose_flag) {
     argv[arg++] = "-v";
   }

   if (!e_flag) {
     argv[arg++] = "-L";
   }

   snprintf(argv[arg++], strlen(defines_path) + 1, "-F\"%s\"", defines_path);
   snprintf(argv[arg++], strlen(defines_path) + 1, "-f\"%s\"", source_path);
   snprintf(argv[arg++], strlen(defines_path) + 1, "-f\"%s\"", compiled_defines_path);

   ivlpp_main(argc, argv);
 }
```

Comment: there are multiple arguments not a single string

Comment: Completed. Now, it should to the job

Comment: If i am try to do like that then it will be ok or not

Comment: static void build_preprocess_command(int e_flag)
{
char  arg0[] = "%s%civlpp";
char  arg1[] = "%s%s";
char  arg2[] = "-F\”%s\”";
char  arg3[] = "-f\”%s\”";
char  arg4[] = "-p\”%s\”";
char  arg5[] = "-v";
char  arg6[] = "-L";
char **argv[] = { &arg0[0], &arg1[0], &arg2[0], &arg3[0], &arg4[0], &arg5[0], &arg6[0],  NULL };
int   argc   = 7;//(int)(sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0])) - 1;
ivlpp_main(argc,argv);
}